# Material UI table components decomposition strange behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markup, material-ui

I use table from [Material UI react components library](http://www.material-ui.com/).
I need to add some custom behavior to TableRow, so I try to decomposite it (and I'm planning to wrap it in my component to add some additional ui and logics).

So, when I try to decomposite [table component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) - it's breaks markup. As you can see checkboxes are absent.

## [See Demo](http://www.webpackbin.com/VkIJ6vRcb)

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn} from 'material-ui/Table';

const MyTableRow = () => {
  return <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>;
}

const TableExampleSimple = () => (
  <Table>
    <TableHeader>
      <TableRow>
        <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>

      <MyTableRow />
      <MyTableRow />
      <MyTableRow />

      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
);

export default TableExampleSimple;
```

What is the reason of such behavior?

## UPD

There is an assumption: [TableBody clones children components](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Table/TableBody.js#L189).
But I still don't know what is the best practice of decomposition of Table components and add some custom behavior. Can anybody explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking up the table components into separate components (if that is what you mean by "decomposite") should work correctly.

I have edited your example so that each of the rows are encapsulated in a separate component.

http://www.webpackbin.com/VyxHMxyo-

Or do you have a hard requirement that prevents you from having all of the rows in a separate component?

Comment: Unfortunately in your example I see the same problem: checkboxes are absent. And if you add native TableRow components you will see the problem.
I want to break table into my own components, each of them would wrap native Table components and add some aditional behavior - this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479568/material-ui-tablerow-wrapped-in-component-wont-show-checkbox).

How I fix my problem:

## [Demo](http://www.webpackbin.com/Eyci0q1iW)

```
const MyTableRow = (props) => {
  return <TableRow {...props}>
    { props.children[0] }
    <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>;
}
```